# List of questions I voted on

Tags: support, voting

Is there a page where you can view what you have voted on?

Comment: [meta.scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/) purposes are bugs, features and discussions about [scifi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/). Your question is a general question about the SE engine. It will get a faster and better answers in [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). FYI for next time :)

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

On [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/70/benstraw?tab=votes) you can see a list of all votes (up, down, close, reopen, deletion, undeletion) that you have cast and on which posts you cast them.

The URL is `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/[user-id]/[user-name]?tab=votes` (fill in your own user ID and user name to see a list of your votes; you can't see anyone else's).

Comment: Except for those posts which have been deleted, at least if you’re a mere mortal like me.

Comment: @amaretto I'll have to take your word for that one :-) *note to self: set up sock account to retain links with mortality*

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - **no**.

Why? See [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48830/possible-to-search-questions-i-voted-on/48913#48913).
But if you insist, see [this trick for viewing your downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51931/query-to-get-questions-i-voted/51932#51932).

Comment: This answer is obsolete.